# HDD rack container

Tags: hard-disk, rack

It should give power to them, and give a SATA connection to them. Roughly so:

[image: HDD rack mount]

...except that I want to put 3.5'' SATA drives in it.

What I want, externally: simple SATA slots, connected to the drives directly. All "intelligent" solutions, particularly complex NAS servers, etc. are all big no-no. I only want a physical storage for the hard disks, the NAS part is done by me.

Nice to have, **but not a requirement**, if at least some of the HDDs can be hot-swapped (removed without screws).

Price should be consequent to the near-zero electronics. (Obviously it should be cheaper than a NAS.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rack-mounted JBOD (Just a Box Of Disks) 19" enclosure for 3.5" SATA drives.

[8 bays for 3.5" drives](https://www.newegg.com/raid-machine-n1208rm/p/1UW-0036-00098?Description=jbod%20enclosure&cm_re=jbod_enclosure-_-9SIADZY5VP3461-_-Product)

[12 bays for 3.5" drives](https://www.newegg.com/istarusa-dage412u20-3ms-silver/p/N82E16816215154?Description=jbod%20enclosure&cm_re=jbod_enclosure-_-16-215-154-_-Product)

Both are hot-swap compatible *if your controller supports that*. Controller cables are readily available from that source, once you make a selection of what you want, but the standard SATA port on a motherboard is designed to control just one drive, so for an enclosure like this, you will need a [2-port JBOD controller](https://www.newegg.com/syba-sd-via-1a2s-sata-ide/p/N82E16816124009) (or more ports) for the number of SATA drives you plan to use.

19" rack-mount drives the price up; if you would accept a freestanding cabinet, [the price drops](https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=jbod%20enclosure%203%2E5%22&PageSize=96&order=PRICE), but you would need to specify the number of drive bays.

Comment: Please also see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers